# SQL Syntax Error SQL46010

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

While converting one of our old DB projects to `MS SQL Server 2012`, we ran into following error:

```
SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near =*.
```

What exactly is this `=*` syntax. We have statements like following in stored procedure

```
Table1.x =* Table1.y
```

Comment: Deprecated outer join syntax.

Comment: @ppeterka66: SQL Server 2012 from OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=*` is the deprecated outer join.

Also check [Avoid using deprecated syntax when you join tables or views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)